# Filtering dataframe based on list of dates in python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime

I have the following dataframe

```
                             response
01/09/2020 07:00:00 AM         1.345
01/09/2020 07:01:00 AM         2.567
01/09/2020 07:02:22 AM         5.999
01/09/2020 07:03:30 AM         4.800
01/09/2020 07:04:07 AM         8.720
01/09/2020 07:05:09 AM         0.999
... 
02/05/2020 11:57:42 PM         8.213
02/05/2020 11:58:03 PM         2.873
02/05/2020 11:59:55 PM         3.875
```

I want to filter out rows that correspond to this list of dates

```
list =  [01/10/2020, 01/11/2020, 01/14/2020, 01/16/2020, 01/20/2020, 02/01/2020, 02/03/2020, 02/04/2020]
```

There are multiple times corresponding to days and I want to keep all of them and drop only the rows that are not in the list of dates.

I am new to Python and have been struggling with this for quite some time, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Tip: never ever name your list, `list`. Call it list1 or something. It will overwrite what a list is to Python.

Comment: How it is called the column that contains the dates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isin` to check for membership in the list of dates.  Ensure that the list of dates is datetime, and that the `floor` of the DataFrame dates are used:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates) # list in your original
df = df[df.index.floor('D').isin(dates)]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020', '01-10-2020', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'response':np.random.rand(len(dr))}, index=dr)

dates = ['01-01-2020', '01-05-2020', '01-07-2020']
dates = pd.to_datetime(dates)

df = df[df.index.floor('D').isin(dates)]
```

Answer (score 2):

first you need to change your date_time column to date_only (or add a new date_only column)
and then apply appropriate filter, assuming you are using pandas you could do something like

```
# assuming your first column name is 'date_time'
df['date_only'] = df['date_time'].dt.date
df = df[~df.date_only.isin(list_of_dates)]
```

Comment: apparently, this didn't work. it creates the date_only column but does not match correctly to the list